# Customizing Windows XP clock

Tags: windows-xp, clock

I'm currently using the great `tclockex` program to change my Windows clock, so it also displays the current week number. The only downside is that it messes up the XP layout:

[image]

You can match the color setting but there's no option to place the clock at another location, messing up my display. Any alternatives?

Comment: If it does not have to be in the system tray, try Yahoo Widgets...http://widgets.yahoo.com/upgrade/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the taskbar being double height you can achieve the same effect by unlocking the taskbar, clicking the top edge when you see the resize arrow and dragging upwards, this way you get more room for programs and a clock with the current date.

It'll look a bit like this (but blue):

[image]

Otherwise you can have a wallclock type thing which has a Windows XP theme:

[image]

from http://oskamp.dyndns.org/SiemensClock/Desktop/

Comment: I use the first option :)

Comment: I used the 1st option as well, but it doesn't display the week number, for instance.